# How to pass the data from backbone.js's client to server. Express + Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, express

I'm trying to pass the data from client to server via Backbone.js's save() method.

### todo.js

```
window.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize:function(){
        },
        urlRoot:"http://localhost:3000/api/todos",
        defaults:{
            title:"",
            done:false,
            important:false,
            completed:false
        },
        toggleDone:function(){
            this.destroy();
        }

});
```

### app.js(Express)

```
app.post("/api/todos",function(req,res){
        console.log(req.title); // I want to receive todo item's title which is created new item's.But req.title is undefined.

});
```

### app_view.js(Backbone.js) is like this...

```
... 


 // create method make new todoItem and send new todoItem to server.But currently it doesn't work.


create:function(e){

var input = $(this.el).find("#new-todo");
 if (e.keyCode !== 13) return;
   var text = input.val();
   var todo = new Todo({title:text});
    // It send POST request to "/api/todos"
   todo.save({title: text,body: "hello world"});
   var todoView = new TodoView({model: todo});
    $("#todo-item").append(todoView.render().$el);
                        $(input).val("");
                        this.collection.add(todo);
                    }
        });
```

This code doesn't send data pass from client to server.
Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model data won't be directly on the request object in Express (req.title).

Assuming you've configured express to use the [bodyParser()](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-bodyParser.html) to parse HTTP POST Bodies

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Then your Backbone model will be in request.data:

```
app.post("/api/todos",function(req,res){
        console.log(req.body.title);

});
```